# HTML5 video player converter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm developing a site where users can publish their videos (similar to YouTube). Is there a way to make my website automatically convert mp4 file to ogg and webm? Are there any plugins? It would be great if you dropped a link to a plugin that is small and powerful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your best bet would be to spin up a server install FFMPEG and then on upload batch process with the following

```
ffmpeg -i INPUTFILE -b 1500k -vcodec libx264 -vpre baseline -g 30 OUTPUT.mp4

ffmpeg -i INPUTFILE -b 1500k -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -ab 160000 -f webm -g 30 OUTPUT.webm

ffmpeg -i INPUTFILE -b 1500k -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -ab 160000 -g 30 OUTPUT.ogv
```

Comment: what about instaling FFMPEG to my server?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ffmpeg#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=ffmpeg%20install&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=605e73b57f23f9c6&biw=890&bih=728&pf=p&pdl=500

Answer (score 0):

You will need a software or a service to this working. If you have root access on your machine, you can try ffmpeg. If you don't have root access, you can utilize an external service like Zencoder for this, but this will cost you some money.